# NativeScript: Vue and Firebase..how can I access the DB after connecting firebase?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am using NativeScript Vue and successfully added firebase.
My `main.js` looks as follows right now:

```
import App from './components/App'
import store from './store';

import VueDevtools from 'nativescript-vue-devtools'

import firebase from 'nativescript-plugin-firebase';
firebase.init({
  // Optionally pass in properties for database, authentication and cloud messaging,
  // see their respective docs.
}).then(
 instance => {
   console.log('firebase.init done');
 },
 error => {
   console.log('firebase.init error: ${error}');
 }
);
Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase;

if(TNS_ENV !== 'production') {
  Vue.use(VueDevtools)
}
// Prints Vue logs when --env.production is *NOT* set while building
Vue.config.silent = (TNS_ENV === 'production')


Vue.component('About',  require('./components/About.vue').default);


new Vue({
  store,
  firebase,
  render: h => h('frame', [h(App)])
}).$start()
```

I noticed that the line of code `Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase;` makes it possible to reference the firebase instance in my `.vue` files with `this.$firebase`.  In my App.vue file, I logged `this.$firebase` and got the following:

```
instance: null,
firebaseRemoteConfig: null,
currentAdditionalUserInfo: null,
authStateListeners: [ [length]: 0 ],
_receivedNotificationCallback: null,
_dynamicLinkCallback: null,
admob:
{ [__esModule]: true,
AD_SIZE:
{ SMART_BANNER: 'SMART',
LARGE_BANNER: 'LARGE',
BANNER: 'BANNER',
MEDIUM_RECTANGLE: 'MEDIUM',
FULL_BANNER: 'FULL',
LEADERBOARD: 'LEADERBOARD',
SKYSCRAPER: 'SKYSCRAPER',
FLUID: 'FLUID' },
showBanner: { [Function: showBanner] [length]: 1, [name]: 'showBanner', [prototype]: [Object] },
```

But how can I set data or write data on it?  I tried write dating both the iOS way and Web way listed in the firebase docs ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ ) but to no avail.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Firestore, checkout the [plugin docs](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/FIRESTORE.md) for all available methods to read / write.

Comment: I am using Real Time database.  I can actually write to the DB successfully by doing this: `this.$firebase.push('/items', { test: "Yes" })` and when I check the firebase dashboard, I can see that get written.  I just can't figure out how to read from it.

Comment: @Manoj I found the RealTime Database documentation in the link you included.  Tahnk you!